# iOS UIViewController pushViewController issue

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I've subclass UINavigationController like this:

```
@implementation BaseNavigationController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.95 blue:0.95 alpha:1];
}

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.viewControllers.count) {
        viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    }
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}
```

And also I've a subclass of UIViewController like this:

```
@implementation BaseViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.95 blue:0.95 alpha:1];
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```

All my view controller are inheriting the baseViewController and all my navigation controller are inheriting the baseNavigationController.

UITabBarViewController -> BaseNavigationController -> BaseViewController

The issue is sometimes when my application is back from background and tap a cell (UITableView or UICollectionView), pushViewController do not work, and the app get stuck.Or sometimes only navigation bar pushed to next view controller,shows next view controller's title and the app also get stuck.The next view controller's viewDidLoad method is called.

I've worried for a week and I do not know why this is happened,so please help me to fix this odd issue.

Not 100% get this issue ,only sometimes.Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to upload your project somewhere and allow us to download so that we can play around with that? May be you can create a seperate project with sample interfaces where this issue happens.

Comment: I suspect that the problem has nothing to do with the code (too short extract) you showed us, your problem will probably still exists even when not subclassing...